# Android getting Error in Google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, manifest

Actually am try to display Google maps using below code but unable to get maps.

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initializeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initializeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeMap();
}
}
```

XML file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

```
This is Manifest file

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.googlemaps.nag"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="com.googlemaps.nag.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.googlemaps.nag.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.googlemaps.nag.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAqr4ThXEtIxeRRFfh1XF2xzWmNU6unPGY" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4323000" />
</application>
```

'EDIT': Am getting this error

ERROR log

```
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.googlemaps.nag/com.googlemaps.nag.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1892)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.googlemaps.nag.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   ... 11 more
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at maps.e.bh.a(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at etu.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
 05-08 15:22:28.407: E/AndroidRuntime(19916):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
```

Comment: There is an error in your AndroidManifest.xml
The two meta tags must be like this:-

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/>

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget to add API Key `<meta-data>` tag in your `manifest.xml` file like

```
  <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="key" />
```

and your mistake is you have added `<meta-data>` version tag two times

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="AIzaSyAqr4ThXEtIxeRRFfh1XF2xzWmNU6unPGY" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="4323000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace this 
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="AIzaSyAqr4ThXEtIxeRRFfh1XF2xzWmNU6unPGY" />
With this
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAqr4ThXEtIxeRRFfh1XF2xzWmNU6unPGY" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that in manifest, your meta-data with that long alpha-numeric key should have the name

```
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
```